# When will the new Stack Overflow badge design come to other sites?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

It looks like Stack Overflow has a new box for badges on the [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=profile):

[image]

However, it appears this has not been rolled out to other sites, such as Code Golf. This is quite a nice design, so when can we expect to see it on other sites too? Or will it be only for Stack Overflow for a while, like the dark theme? Unlike the dark theme, it appears this feature hasn't been added to [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/189350/user?tab=profile) and [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/449077/user?tab=profile).

Comment: [Here's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408611/new-badge-ui-on-profile-page) a post on MSO asking about this, although it doesn't have any answers yet.

Comment: the MSO post has [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408614/8200485) now

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Not an answer to this question.  Cody posted a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408611/new-badge-ui-on-profile-page/408614#comment850678_408614); waiting for a response.

Comment: An update:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408611/what-is-the-new-badge-ui-on-the-profile-page/408614?noredirect=1#comment850713_408614

Comment: Design borrowed from here: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/151/51

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This new profile UI for badges has now been rolled out to all sites across the Stack Exchange network. We also fixed a pluralization bug while we were at it. Here's a few examples:

| Site | Image |
| --- | --- |
| [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/718314/kyle-pollard?tab=profile) | [image: a screenshot of the new badge UI on Meta Stack Exchange] |
| [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/263137/kyle-pollard?tab=profile) | [image: a screenshot of the new badge UI on Arqade] |
| [RPG Stack Exchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/57937/kyle-pollard?tab=profile) | [image: a screenshot of the new badge UI on RPG Stack Exchange] |

Comment: Just to check, site-specific badge shapes won't revert to a plain "star in laurels" design, right?

Comment: @Jenayah The larger "star in laurels" design is used as a [spot illustration](https://stackoverflow.design/product/resources/spots/#awardlg) for this badge component on the profile page. [The badge component in general](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/badges/) will continue to have their site-specific badge shapes when this updated profile goes across the network. For example, here's how the design will look on scifi: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Zvq.png

Comment: @KylePollard Where do you want bug reports/feedback for this now it's live to the rest of the network? I assume not here so is there a general post or tag you want us to use?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot there's no collection post for bugs on this, so just a new post tagged with `[bug]`, `[badges]`, and `[profile-page]` would work 

Comment: @KylePollard Great, [I've posted the bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368273/345161).

Comment: Is there a button in bronze badge block if a user don't have even single one badge?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ There is, but it's unlikely to show up since the entire badge section is hidden if you don't have any badges. You would somehow need a silver or gold badge but not a bronze.

Comment: @KylePollard seems weird for me. But anyway could you please provide a screenshot or at least title of that button in bronze badge block? I need to know it to make a translation for ruSO.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ The text for the bronze section is "You don't have a bronze badge yet. Read more about how badges work and how to earn them." if it's your profile, or "This user doesn't have any bronze badges yet." if it's not your profile. The button says "Learn more about badges" and links to `/help/badges`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 13):

According to a [comment on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408611/what-is-the-new-badge-ui-on-the-profile-page/408614?noredirect=1#comment850713_408614) by staff member [Piper Lawson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7851896/piper-lawson):

> the Public Platform team will get this scheduled for an upcoming sprint

So yes, you *can* expect the changes described in [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408614/6380541) to be rolled out networkwide eventually (note that the comment talks about *an* upcoming sprint, not *the*), and it won't be something for Stack Overflow only.