# Link to own profile has disappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, mobile-web, responsive-design

Maybe I am crazy, but I cannot find a way to get to my profile page anymore, while browsing from Android/Chrome.

I think the profile link showed up after clicking on the logo in the top left.

[image]

[image]

I tried clicking every other thing at the top. I also tried going to the desktop site by clicking the link in the footer. I found the link to my profile there, but it is unreadable small on my phone,  and the "responsive design" button does not appear to change that at all.

[image]

So far the best workaround seems to be googling for one of my posts, then clicking on my name. Since I read that there will be no more bugfixes for the mobile site, is that just how it is going to be?

Comment: You're not crazy (or maybe I am too). I noticed the same here, the link used to be on the top bar, next to inbox, but now it's gone. I'm using iOS 14.7.1/Chrome 92.0.4515.90

Comment: Probably caused by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Additional profile refinements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368661/additional-profile-refinements)

Comment: @Luuklag no, not at all? that appears to be about some new design of the profile page itself. my question is about trying to find the link to the profile page.

Comment: I talked to the Stacks team, this is related to the deprecation of the mobile views but it's a bug that got introduced - it's a bit late today but they're going to have a fix for it tomorrow. :) Thanks for your patience! Apologies for the inconvenience. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@Catija is correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368666/link-to-own-profile-has-disappeared#comment1229856_368666), this is a bug was related to our deprecation of the mobile views.

We've shipped a fix for this so the link to your profile should be back now! Sorry for the trouble and thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: Could this fix have caused this new issue? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368759/opening-the-burger-menu-while-in-the-profile-page-shows-a-link-to-my-profile