# Extra user card and two "log out" links in the Stack Exchange menu

Tags: bug, design, stack-exchange-button, responsive-design

#### Update Feb 19, 2022:

This was *partially* fixed a while ago (i.e., on desktop mode) but just reappeared on all pages of Meta Stack Exchange, specifically (I can't repro on other sites):

[image: The Stack Exchange drop-down menu on a random Meta Stack Exchange page]

---

#### Original post:

I noticed that when I open the Stack Exchange menu on desktop while on the [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) (mine or another user's), it includes my user card, which a) takes some real estate from the drop-down menu, b) messes up with my muscle memory when I try to visit a site, and c) is redundant because it's already there in the top bar.

Actually, it depends on the device / screen resolution. Here are the details:

| Device/Screen | Page | Behavior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Desktop**, full window | Any page except profile | The menu looks normal (the way it used to) |
| **Desktop**, full window | [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) | Extra user card + extra "log out" link |
| **Mobile** / narrow screen (**responsive**) | Any page | User card + extra "log out" link |

For desktop, here are the two views side by side:

| Profile Page | Other pages |
| --- | --- |
| [image: The Stack Exchange drop-down menu on profile pages] | [image: The Stack Exchange drop-down menu on other pages] |

This bug was likely introduced by this [recent fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368745/348196).

I think the user card should be removed from both the "wide view" (e.g., desktops) and narrow-screen view (e.g., responsive design on mobile phones). But if it's decided that it should be shown on narrow-screen views (for rep and badges), then at least one "log out" link should be removed.

This is how it currently looks on responsive design on mobile (all pages):

[image: The Stack Exchange drop-down menu on narrow screens]

**Addendum:** As [zcoop98](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/776523/zcoop98) pointed out in the comments, the two "log out" links are also shown on the mobile view (not responsive).

Comment: I think this is done by them with their wish and it is not a bug. It is the way system is designed

Comment: @JitendraSingh I don't think so because it's currently only shown when opening the menu on the profile page as explained above (except on narrow screens where it's shown everywhere).

Comment: @4168d I meant the same. This is a intentional feature. They have made it this way in profile page only so that others also could see their profile while seeing others

Comment: "Burger menu"? Isn't that just the Stack Exchange logo (upper right)?

Comment: @P.Mort Yes, I've seen it called that a few times before; so, I thought it's recognized by that name. Feel free to edit the post if you can use a more descriptive title.

Comment: @JitendraSingh, but you could simply click your avatar in the top bar (with black background) to see your own profile.

Comment: It feels weird to have _both_ the [[tag:mobile-web]] and [[tag:responsive-design]] tags on one post, but it seems appropriate given that you've shown that the bug exists in both views.

Comment: @zcoop98 AFAICT, [mobile-web] is for the deprecated soon-to-be-removed mobile view. That's not what I was talking about (even though it's affected by the two "log out" links). I was referring to the responsive design both on desktop and on narrow screens (two different behaviors).

Comment: @416 I refer specifically to the doubled log-out, which as you point out, does exist in the now-deprecated mobile-web view. That's why I added the tag. If you don't feel it's appropriate, that's fine. I just thought it made sense since that bug exists in both (responsive & mobile) views.

Comment: @zcoop98 Yes, I noticed that before I commented. So, you're right about the mobile view being affected. However, all the screenshots in the question are of the responsive design (desktop and mobile). Let me add a note at the end about the mobile view as well.

Comment: @41686d6564 Oh! Is that third screenshot not of the mobile view?

Comment: @41686d6564 I made a mistake; you're right. I was sitting here thinking that that last screenshot was the mobile web view, not the responsive view on a mobile-sized screen. I apologize for the confusion, I can see why you didn't add that tag now.

Comment: @zcoop98 Yep, exactly. No worries :) I did check though and the bug exists on the mobile view too. That's why I added a note about it.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, on mobile (or narrow screens), it's on all pages. However, on desktop, it's only on the profile page for some reason.