# Two log out links in mobile web view

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

Clicking on the logo in the top left in the browser on a mobile device displays a dialog with *two* log out links:

[image]

I experienced this with Safari on an iPhone. It is the same on all sites. Perhaps it is related to the recent fix of [Link to own profile has disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368666/link-to-own-profile-has-disappeared)?

Comment: Already mentioned here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368759/294055

Comment: @honk: You are right, I hadn't found that from the title. It is described at the end of that question.