# Always show only one "log out" link

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, stack-exchange-button, logout

Sometimes I see two "log out" links, like this:

[image: 2]

It is always like this on mobile, and on desktop view I see it when looking at my own profile.

On all other pages (other than my own user profile) that I've checked, it appears like this:

[image: 1]

This was confusing to me. When there are two "log out" links, I thought that the top one, which is aligned with my profile, would log me out from all sites, and the second one, which is aligned with "Mathematics", would log me out of Mathematics only.

This is, of course, incorrect; both links go to the same page which logs out of all sites in the network.

To make it clearer, there should always be only one "log out" link. Whether it appears aligned with the profile (which is more intuitive in my opinion), or aligned with the site name, it shouldn't be both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extra user card and two "log out" links in the Stack Exchange menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368759/extra-user-card-and-two-log-out-links-in-the-stack-exchange-menu). Another very similar question is [Two log out links in mobile web view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368769/562482).

Comment: @JohnOmielan I didn't see those questions when searching, but they are tagged [tag:bug], not [tag:feature-request]. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I'm not an expert by any means, but as far as I know, it doesn't really make very much difference which tag is used since the underlying issues, and the proposed changes, are basically the same, but it could affect who views the questions. Nonetheless, I suspect the 2 linked posts use the [tag:bug] tag since the issue appeared recently, with there not being any notice that this change was intentional. Also, I believe a [tag:feature-request] tag is normally used to request a change to intentional behavior. Thus, it seems the [tag:bug] tag would be somewhat more appropriate here.

Comment: @Cody I think this is intentional behaviour, not a bug (it never even occured to me as a bug, for some reason). It was reported before as a bug with no outcome (see top comment). That's why I tagged it feature-request; I want it to be changed.

Comment: The displaying of a double user card is definitely a bug; that should not happen. And it *doesn't* happen for me (never has), so different behavior for different users is a bug, too.

Comment: I didn't know of the different behaviour for different users. Bug it is then.

Comment: Interestingly, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368759/extra-user-card-and-two-log-out-links-in-the-stack-exchange-menu) question reports it happening on *any* profile page, whereas I only see it on *my own* profile page.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I always thought it was on purpose...

Comment: @Cody You don't see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSHYC.png) when opening the menu _on the profile page_? Or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhgZj.png) when opening the menu on mobile?

Comment: @41686d6564 Ah, I do see it on my profile! I am not sure about mobile; can't test that at the moment. But I still think this is a bug!

Comment: @Cody Yeah, it is. I'm actually the author of the original bug report. It wasn't like that before and it doesn't make sense to show two "Log out" links.