# We’ve shipped some changes to the user profile navigation

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page, mobile-web, announcements

The changes discussed and demoed in [Additional profile refinements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368661/additional-profile-refinements) are now getting rolled out.

We’re changing some layout before enabling responsiveness on user profiles. However, we can’t enable responsiveness fully on these pages until the entirety of the page stretches and wraps appropriately. For now, we’re only rolling out the top bits. You’ll still get horizontal scrolling on the bottom of 3/4 of the page. Further refinement will move down the page as we go.

If you see anything goofy, or if something feels like a bug on the top there, please let us know in an answer below. Try to include your browser and OS versions if you find anything. I’ll do the best I can to respond to the lot of you while balancing my daily tasks—and staring down that huge roadmap item of [deprecating all the mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views).

**Large**

[image]

**Medium**

[image]

**Small**

[image]

Comment: D'ya think you could make the bit at the top - profile pic, username, etc. - a bit smaller?  It's really huge and in my face right now.

Comment: That little dashboard there is... not easy to see.  You threw me for a loop there when i needed to access the mod dashboard info for a user...

Comment: Recognizing that this is just one step toward a completely responsive profile  and ignoring other issues from prior changes, I think this is a good step. I know some people aren’t going to like the “transition” phase profile for reasons that would be reasonable if it was the final result, but since I’ve met my nitpicking quota for the day, I wanted you to know my first impression was positive even if I find something I don’t like tomorrow :)

Comment: Would it be possible to remove the "Network profiile" button? Some users prefer to have different names and therefore different identities on different SE sites so its removal would be cool.... just my own opinion.

Comment: @Nobodyimportant That's technically already possible, unless I'm misunderstanding your request. If you hide a profile on a specific community, the network profile link will only be shown to mods.

Comment: @Catija: Sure... but there's another thing that can show you other users' SE accounts and their activity. If you go to the "activity" section in my profile and then click the "Accounts" link, you will see all my activity on other sites even though I've hidden all my other SE accounts. (Try it in incognito or from another account because you're  a staff member and can see everything.)

Comment: But that's completely unrelated to your request. Hiding the network link doesn't prevent it from showing in at least one other place on the page, so it's less useful than just using the tooling we already have, @Nobodyimportant

Comment: I really don't like the drop down, kinda annoyinig to now need to click twice to get where i need when it was immediately available before. What else would potentially go in that drop down than a link to the main site/child meta and the network profile? I personally find the network profile to be 100% useless, but don't recall where a link to it existed prior to this.

Comment: @KevinB The link was available in a couple different places. The network profile is useful for seeing what accounts (linked, anyway) the user has on other sites and how active they are there across different parameters, and there are user scripts to show additional things there as well (e.g. the Global Flag Summary from StackApps). The network profile link is still available as a standalone link (e.g. not behind a dropdown menu) in the network profiles section of the user profile page.

Comment: @Nobodyimportant You can create accounts without linking them together; just do that if you don't want people to know who you are on SO, etc.

Comment: Don't forget that the dropdown allows Teams users to switch between their profiles on Teams. This dropdown can have `n` links.

Comment: so, effectively muddying up the "view meta profile" link network-wide to support teams

Comment: So.. now mobile users are stuck with a fixed top bar *and* a huge top part on the profile page that will show up even if they just want to see the activity?

Comment: So is this supposed to be responsive right now? Because for me it is just the entire page [crammed onto my tiny screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKhjh.jpg). No horizontal scroll (which would be even worse IMHO).

Comment: Why is "reached" still there? It's still a nonsense and "vanity" stat; or has this profile change finally made an effort to change the logic?.

Comment: @Luuklag Yeah, I'm struggling to get any view besides the "Large" view, regardless of screen size

Comment: I don't think that the different views will "work" until the full page is responsive. My guess is that for the screenshots, Aaron removed the rest of the page content (since it's not visible).

Comment: @Catija Ironically, someone made the page *responsive* without rearranging everything and posted a script on Stack Apps. It was very nice.. until it was broken.

Comment: @Catija That’s right. I have a flag locally that allows responsiveness. The pages are not responsive in production _yet_.

Comment: @AaronShekey that is not clear at all from your post.

Comment: Now the profile page is looking nicer...

Answer (score 28):

I do have a few things I'd like fixed:

1. Please make the top bit of the profile - the profile pic, etc. - a bit smaller.  The new setting means there is a gigantic amount of whitespace to the right of the profile unless you fill it up with mod links, a large About Me, etc.  Something like this would be preferable, so it's not in our faces:

[image]

2. I would like the the "Network profile" and "Go to Meta" links put back as bare links instead of in a dropdown, which just adds extra clicks.  There are never more than two links to each profile on that page (and the links to your Teams are unnecessary because they're in the left nav), so the links wouldn't look any worse than the current setup.  I suggest something like this (without the pencil):

   [image]
3. *Please* bring back the Last Seen metric, as it was.  I know I've said it before, but with the new changes, it's still a no-show.

Comment: Heh, on this site, there is no Meta, so the drop down has only ONE option. You just don't use drop-downs with a single options.

Comment: @Adám yeah, but on SO, there's *two*!

Comment: Others count "one, two, many". Stack Exchange counts "one, many".

Comment: I agree about dropdowns never having only a single option. We had to punt for technical reasons on that one, but it _will_ be revisited.

Comment: I agree with all suggestions but especially making profile pic smaller. The top part is a bit too *heavy*.

Comment: @AaronShekey Thanks, that's good to hear.

Comment: @AaronShekey I disagree with this, if the top pic gets smaller it won't be large enough anywhere. It's the only place where you can see a user's pic with reasonable size since the link takes you to the user profile not the image and it would be nuisance to have to click to see the user image anyway.

Comment: My screen resolution is 1600x900. With this huge shared banner on top of all tabs, when I open my "All actions" tab I can only see *one row* of the actual data - the rest space is consumed by the huge header. And I visit my "All actions" [hundreds of time a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368328/147640). I really don't need to be reminded that often *who I am* in an in-your-face fashion. Please make that top line the height of the Edit Profile button. This design is good for showcasing SO members' profiles to a CEO on an iPad. It is *not* good when you actually use the wesbite daily.

Comment: We’ve restored "last seen" to all users, but with less granularity.

Comment: @AaronShekey This week... and more than a week ago.  Why was it chosen to be less accurate?

Answer (score 15):

I am not happy with the current profile:

[image: Profile]

You have this giant empty whitespace on the right, while the actual important
information, like reputation, is all slammed into a small corner on the left.
Also, "reached" should be "users reached", or something with just one or two
words more context, as currently its so vague as to be not useful. Also, I will
echo the many other users who are not happy about "last seen" being killed. I
I used that nearly every day. Also, why is a dropdown being used
for a single item?

[image: Dropdown]

I would like to respond to this comment from Stack Overflow staff:

> How would you expect anyone to make the page recognize that someone has no
> content in that section? Put a box around it? Saying that it's bad doesn't help
> us know what to do better. Yes, it's white space - for you... but not for
> everyone.

This is pretty simple to answer, as you’ve been able to do this with HTML for
literally decades:

```html
<!-- person with a big bio -->
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>small<td>
      <td>big big big big big big big big big big big big big</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<!-- person with a small bio -->
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>big big big big big big big big big big big big big</td>
      <td>small<td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Result:

[image: Tables]

To respond to another comment from Stack Overflow staff:

> This design supports no bio, a paragraph, and incredibly long bios. Got any
> ideas on how to support a one character bio?

The default HTML behavior supports what I am suggesting. I already gave example
code above. To be clear, all you need to do is stop using a fixed width in the
right places and the problem goes away. If a user has small bio, then allow
other elements (repuation or whatever) to either get larger, or spread out
more, or both.

Comment: The “users reached” is a bogus number pulled from thin air with no real meaning. It should be removed now, not months later.

Comment: It's not ugly, it's designed for mobile, and mobile only. Kind of opposite of responsive design.

Comment: It probably makes sense to look at profiles with more content than yours. You have two short lines in your About section, which makes it seem very empty. But my profile is full of text, making it much less white space.

Comment: How would you expect anyone to make the page recognize that someone has no content in that section? Put a box around it? Saying that it's bad doesn't help us know what to do better. Yes, it's white space - for you... but not for everyone.

Comment: We don't plan on having a single item as a dropdown. Had to punt on that one, but it _will_ be fixed.

Comment: @Catija Even with pre-flexbox properties, the normal block model will handle that issue just fine; if there is no content in the "about" box, it will--*by default*--collapse to zero height. The SO design team would've had to intentionally alter the default behavior to get it to retain its height here, so I would assume Steven would prefer the default block behavior be restored.

Comment: This design supports no bio, a paragraph, and incredibly long bios. Got any ideas on how to support a one character bio?

Comment: @StevenPenny Should we be measuring characters in user bios and changing the layout based on that? How many characters is the threshold? Do newlines count? How many characters is a 3000 x 3000 image?

Comment: @AaronShekey you set a `min-width` on the reputation column, and a `min-width` on the bio column, and thats it. The browser can then let the content itself decide what to do, without any JavaScript. Big bios will take up more space, small bios will take up less.

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The user group section was introduced. If I'm part of one group, the label displayed as "1 user groups", can it be updated to "1 user group"

[image: group]

Comment: What *is* a user group?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Seems they couldn't remember their name for collectives https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408585/2777074

Comment: Issue fixed and noted here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411224/rename-user-groups-to-collectives-on-the-so-profile-page/411227#411227

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Code blocks overflow™ in the About section, creating an annoying horizontal scrollbar on the page:

[image]

Here's a [profile page](https://stackapps.com/users/76056/spectric?tab=profile) showcasing this issue.

Comment: @StevenPenny You would rather it create a scrollbar on the entire screen than it wrapping?

Comment: I would rather people not put full programs in a single line of code

Comment: Luckily the Internet Archive can show us how it used to look before/after the changes. Looking at [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael)'s profile [before](https://web.archive.org/web/20210831121012/https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) and [after](https://web.archive.org/web/20210902011948/https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) the changes, there were previously scroll bars for the code to prevent a scroll bar for the whole page.

Answer (score 10):

Everything is tiny on mobile when I view the profile. I am currently on chrome 92 on a OnePlus 9 Pro running android 11 on a 2340x1080 (6.7 inch) display.

I can't read anything, and I use this view multiple times a day for moderation purposes. I've added a screenshot of the 'main' mod page below but the other pages have the same issue.

Could y'all test potentially breaking changes on a *range* of devices and screen sizes including *modern phones* before shipping?

From what I can tell, (And I don't have any pre-change phone screenshots of profiles on hand) - it seems 'stuck' in the desktop/wide screen view of a responsive screen, with the left sidebar which would collapse normally as well... only scaled to fit what should be a wider width into a small screen.

And its not responsiveness, the rest of the site works fine. This is a *breaking change*, and there is literally no way I can get *vital functionality* back. I can't nuke spammers. I can't read profiles. I can't read the user moderation tools.  And since its mobile, even if some clever person get a userscript to fix it, it dosen't quite help me.

And the *regular* site pages scale just fine - its just the profile pages - do y'all actually can do the same thing you did there

And while I'm averse to the sticky top bar... I can't even click on it on this size with my normal human hands.

[image]

Yes, it looks fine on my 4k screen. View on its own, on a phone to get an idea of how it is

Comment: Its not ugly, its unusable.

Comment: Hasn't it been tiny before the change? I don't think this update changed the size. You have to pinch to zoom on mobile same as before. It's not responsive yet.

Comment: I used to use it every day on my phone. It wasn't this bad, trust me. I do a lot of moderation on the phone, and this includes deleting spammers - and linking other mods to network profiles. This is *impossible* with how tiny this is.

Comment: At least it made *you* responsive ;)

Comment: I'm always responsive. Unless I am asleep.... Or require medical attention 

Comment: This page is not responsive yet. My post says “ we can’t enable responsiveness fully on these pages until the entirety of the page stretches and wraps appropriately”. When the rest of the page has a flexible layout you’ll see the correct viewport sizing.

Comment: In which case it's completely broken compared to what it was till it's fixed for anyone on mobile? This.... is a pretty big problem for me. I moderate on mobile. This essentially makes a good chunk of what I do impossible until I am on a PC.

Comment: It's not a great solution, but maybe you can use the Mobile view until the profile is responsive? @AaronShekey Is the plan that the Mobile view won't be deprecated completely until the profile page is completely transitioned?

Comment: @ColleenV Right, mobile view isn't going away until that profile page is _completely_ responsive. Just the top bit is _ready_ for responsiveness, but the page itself doesn't have it enabled. It's an annoying bit of staging we have to do in order for this work to be incremental.

Answer (score 10):

With the new layout , the GitHub and Twitter icons are so small and occupy just a tiny space which makes them hard to find and click.

I think they should be accompanied with a label or have a little more margin from each other.

[image]

Comment: As a side note, how am I supposed to know those icons represent GitHub and Twitter? I mean, sure, a lot of people do, but first timers don't. The same way I never ever knew the funnel used by so many apps actually meant "filter" until someone said it was.

Comment: These links are likely to be too small for mobile. Maybe adding the label “Twitter” and “GitHub”, respectively, after the icon is a good option.

Comment: I made some personal changes, so to me it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug1wG.png)

Comment: @SebastianSimon Once the full profile is finished, they shouldn't be too small - they look a decent size in the third screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [tooltip](/questions/tagged/tooltip) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Apply tooltip, if the text is truncated by an ellipsis.

In the below screenshot, the location is partially visible. On hover over on the text, unable to see the full text. In this case, the full text can be displayed in the tooltip.

[image: full text]

Comment: I think you should come run quality assurance / testing at Stack Overflow 

Comment: @AaronShekey I hope this is not a sarcastic reply :)

Comment: I mean it completely earnestly. Thank you for all the reports!

Comment: @AaronShekey Oh, Okay. Thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: Can we think about a solution other than a tooltip which excludes people on touch devices? @AaronShekey

Comment: @ColleenV a tiny popover showing the full text if you tap on the truncated word/ellipsis?

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight That’s what I was thinking, but I try to keep myself from getting too specific when I don’t know much about the code. I think being too specific about what I want sometimes diverts folks with more knowledge from creative solutions I would never have thought of.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is no option listed in the "Profiles" dropdown list for a few of the users. Usually "Network profile" link is listed there.

Sample users:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/665544
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/237989

Not sure whether this is due to hidden communities

[image]

Comment: Hey :D I know the user in that picture

Answer (score 6):

Having the profile on top of the **activity tab** doesn't look good and clutters the page of that tab.

- As it looks now

  [image: screenshot of current activity tab]
- I think it would look better like this (username in place of the badges)

  [image: screenshot of possible activity tab]

Comment: What about the user's display name? Also, is this just for the Activity tab or the Profile tab as well?

Comment: @41686d6564 As I said just for activity tab. Name in place of the badges.

Comment: And then on the profile page, the top part should go under the tabs ;)

Answer (score 6):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

How can I have transparency in my avatar on my profile?

My avatar is a word balloon set on a transparent background. However, the top of my profile page shows it on white background which looks (in my opinion) horrible when used on a dark background:

[image: Screenshot of my profile page in dark theme showing the top being a word balloon on while background. Further down there is an avatar chooser which shows the same image on transparent background.]

The top is the avatar with the forced white background and no transparency. The URL for it is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXuSR.png?s=256&g=1

which also *stretches* the image to 256x256px.

The regular sized image is 84x75px:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXuSR.png

And strangely, the image down on the page is a similar size, however it has a transparent background. The URL for that image is https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXuSR.png?s=328&g=1

Is there any way I can have my avatar with a transparent background everywhere? If so - how?

Comment: I think this should deserve a sepparate post, as this is not really related here.

Comment: The answer, inconveniently, is "use Gravatar."  See, for instance, my profile picture, which has a transparent background _almost_ everywhere.

Comment: @Luuklag This is a change since the update. Previously the avatar shown in the profile was shown with transparent background. The problem is that when you use the URL to resize an image from Imgur, it's automatically removing transparency. And SE have chosen to *stretch* the image shown in the profile (top) through manipulating its URL.

Answer (score 4):

Why group the moderator-only links separately from the others? Can you bring the mod links in with the rest of them (left-justified)?

I don't see any need for them to be out on an island on the right; they are sooo far away and disconnected from the profile and other related links. It's especially difficult to find them when on the full site on mobile (Chrome).

I know this is a bit of a temporary request because once everything is responsive it's less important, but I still think it makes more sense to have them in more of the "same place" regardless of sizing. If they overflow to a second row on smaller views, that's fine, but they shouldn't go on a eastbound vacation when the screen is larger.

Comment: I went back and forth on that as well. I was trying to keep _some_ muscle memory for the mods having stuff over on the right. It's also nice to have some conceptual grouping of "sections" on the left and "mod actions" to the right. Product design! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AaronShekey I've already forgotten where they were before, I just know I had trouble finding them for some reason today... I guess I'll probably get used to it, maybe an example of https://xkcd.com/1172/

Answer (score 3):

I get horizontal scrolling on the entire profile page, making the new "Profiles" dropdown particularly difficult to discover/access:

[image: User profile with right-side content hidden due to horizontal scrolling]

I'm using Firefox 91.0.2 on Ubuntu 18 (91.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), although the problem is the same using Chrome 92.0.4515.159 and Chromium 92.0.4515.159.

Comment: "We can’t enable responsiveness fully on these pages until the entirety of the page stretches and wraps appropriately. For now, we’re only rolling out the top bits. You’ll still get horizontal scrolling on the bottom of 3/4 of the page. Further refinement will move down the page as we go."

Comment: @AaronShekey My intent was to point out that the top bits aren't resizing appropriately either (my fault for not editing in a freehand circle). If "the bottom 3/4 of the page" wasn't meant to refer to everything under the sticky header bar, there would seem to be a discrepancy.

Comment: @manveti as long as not everything is resizing, the top will resize together with the widest part of the page. So this is totally by design. It appears as though you are using quite a small screen. Such info would be helpfull to add to a future bug report.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Links on one site aren't automatically converted to post titles on sites other than MSE

On my [Sustainability.SE profile](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/3379/lshaver?tab=profile), I have some links to questions on Sustainability.SE. I've entered these in my profile as raw links:

[image: Screen shot of profile edit dialog]

These render correctly on the live profile on Sustainability.SE **and MSE**, even for users that aren't logged in:

[image: Screen shot of live profile with rendered links]

But on every other site I've checked, only the raw links are shown. Here's a snippet from [my profile on Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/38403/lshaver?tab=profile):

[image: Screen shot of live profile with raw links]

Comment: I didn't notice this until poking around the updated profile -- if it's not related let me know and I can make this a new post.

Comment: I think it has always been that way (or at least it has since I’ve been here). Question links only expand into titles when they’re from the same site.

Comment: @ColleenV except it also works on MSE, which is why I thought something might be up.

Comment: It is intentional that it is only "intra-site" links: [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69483/273494) and enabling the same functionality in comments has been declined. Although I missed the part where it was in your profile, so I don't know about that. Have you tried removing your userid from the end? (for science, not saying that is a perfect work around).

Comment: I just realize I relied on the title in my profile as well, so I played around a bit. You know what's really interesting? When I update my "network" profile, it strips the URL out and just keeps the title. Weird.

Answer (score 3):

As of today (I think, or maybe it was just before the weekend?), the profiles button will change into "Network profile" if there are no other communities to display:

[image: Screenshot of the Meta Stack Exchange profile of Aaron Shekey showing a button labelled "Network profile", which was previously a drop down labelled "Profiles"]

In case one has their accounts set to hidden, the link will not appear:

[image: Screenshot of an account that is set to hidden, the "Network profile" button is not shown]

Comment: Yep! We had to punt on that logic since it was a bit gnarly, but it's now been implemented as designed. No one, not a single person, likes a dropdown with a single option. Glad we could fix it!

Answer (score 2):

## Use AJAX when switching user tabs?

Can we use AJAX instead of reloading the page when switching between user tabs?

When switching between profile tabs, there's a lot that's loaded again, labelled below:

[image]

This redundancy can be removed by loading tab HTML with AJAX, sort of like how snippets work right now. It would personally make the switching tabs experience a lot better.

Comment: This should be a separate feature request. It’s out of scope for this responsiveness change.